# How to disable the whole page under some condition in the code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a specific page ,i want in the button click event and under some condition to disable all the controls and `grayout` the whole page ,showing an information message to state that the confirmation is done .

---

How to do that in a general way ?

Comment: sounds like you want fancybox... http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: in a general way you could use a div that covers all your page. Like the Jquery Modal Dialog confirmation. Or plain JavaScript.

Comment: then after i surround my controls with a parent div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want a mask. Although not exactly to your question look at this jQuery based load mask plugin, you should be able to adapt it to suit your needs:

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the modal popup that is included in the Ajax Control Toolkit:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

This will allow popup of a message that effectively prevents interaction with the rest of the page.

Comment: how to close the main page when the user click `ok` in the modal popup ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if(Conditions satisfy){
    $('#div_controls').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#div_status').attr('disabled', false);}
else{ $('#div_controls').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#div_status').attr('disabled', True)
}

});

In HTML 

<div id="div_status"> Your Message with your styles </div>
<div id="div_controls"> Your Controls inside this Div </div>
```

Without any Post back,WO loosing the data, State  It can be done..

or Check this demo

http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

Answer (score 0):

you can make all controls "invisble" after user click by

```
   foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
        c.Visible = false;
```

Or a better way would be to use plugins such as [Modal-UpdateProgress](http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2008/03/13/Modal-UpdateProgress-for-UpdatePanel-Revisited/)

Answer (score 0):

in HTML

```
<div id="layer"></div>
<div id="container">

   ----
   ----
   ----

</div>
```

and in CSS

```
#layer{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

This will disable the page ( or it will act like disabled ).